# Support any zoom level on non responsive bootstrap application

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have web application developed using bootstrap non-responsive template. 
Currently application supports zoom level 100%. 
My requirement is to work the same application on any zoom level. 
Please suggest how to achieve the same.

Comment: Try removing the `user-scalable=no` from the meta viewport command.

Comment: Please show an example of your result on jsfiddle and describe what exactly you want it to look like.

Comment: My meta tag is <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">